# sprintf or itoa or memcpy for IPC

Tags: c, ipc

A process say PA wants to send values of 2 integers to PB by sending it in a char buf after populating it with values. Assume PA and PB are in same machine. PB knows that the buffer it reads contains values of 2 integers.

```
uint x=1;

uint y=65534;
```

- Case 1

PA writes into char buf as shown

```
sprintf(buff,"%d%d",x,y);
```

Q1 - In this case how will PB able to extract their values as 1 and 65534 since it just has an array containing 1,6,5,5,3,4. Is using `sprintf` the problem?

- Case 2

PA use `itoa` function to populate the value of integers in to buffer.
PB use `atoi` to extract the values from buffer.
Since `itoa` puts a null terminator after each value this should be possible.

Q2 - Now consider PA is running on a 32 bit machine with 4 byte int size and PB is running on a 16 bit machine with 2 byte int size. Will only checking for out of range make my code portable?

Q3 - Is `memcpy` another way of doing this?

Q4 - How is this USUALLY done ?

Comment: The best idea would be not to use ASCII at all unless you are communicating with human - it is the most hardware-unfriendly format to represent the data.

Answer (score 1):

1) The receiver will read the string values from the network, and do its own conversion; in this case it woud get the string representation of 165,534. You need some way of delimiting the values for the receiver.

2) Checking for out of range is a good start, but portability depends on more factors, such as defining a format for the transfer, be it binary or textual.

3) Wha?

4) It's usually done by deciding on a standard for binary representation of the number, i.e., is it a signed/unsigned 16/32/64 bit value, and then converting it into what's commonly referred to as network byte order[1] on the sending side, and converting it to host byte order on the receiving side.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_byte_order#Endianness_in_networking

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have a look into

As you noticed in Case 1 there is no way to extract the values from the buffer if you don't have additional information. So you need some delimitier character.

In Q2 you mention a 16 Bit machine. Not only the #bytes for an int can be a problem but also the endianess and the sign.

What I would do:
- Define an own protocol for different numbers (you can't send a 4 byte int to the 16 bit machine and use the same type without loosing information)
Or
- Check the int (must fit in 2 bytes) before writing.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Not using `sprintf` is the problem, but the way of using it. How about:

```
 sprintf(buff,"%d:%d",x,y);
```

(Note: A comma as seperator could cause problems with international formats)

Q2: No. Other problems, e.g. regarding endianness, could arise

Q3: No if you use different machines. One a single machine, you can (mis)use your buffer as an array of bytes.

Q4: Different ways, e.g. XDR (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation)

---

Comment: Endianess won't be a problem if the data is transferred in string format, which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a protocol and a transport mechanism.

Transport mechanisms include sockets, named pipes, shared memory, SSL etc.

The protocol could be as simple as space separated strings, as you suggested. It could also be something more "complicated" like an XML-based format. Or binary format. 
All these protocol types are in use in various applications. Which protocol to choose depends on your requirements.